# Right Click on a specific row from DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have a `DataGridView` with IP Addresses from my Network and now I am trying to build something which allows me to after right click on a specific row it will open the Explorer of that IP Address.

This is the code I already got:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        int position = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

        if(position >= 0)
        {
            menu.Items.Add("OpenExplorer").Name = "Open Explorer";
        }
        menu.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        menu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(menu_ItemClicked);
    }
}

void menu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        switch (e.ClickedItem.Name.ToString())
        {
            case "OpenExplorer":
                Process.Start(@"\\" + linha.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But it actually does not work because displays an error saying that this path does not exists. Do you have any ideia how to solve it? How I can get the selected row?

Comment: The [`SelectedRows` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't returning what you think it's returning.

Comment: I know. I should use a `Foreach`? @sab669

Comment: How many columns does your `DataGridView` have? And can they actually select multiple rows?

Comment: My `DataGridView` has 5 columns. They selected all the rows from a table, yes. @sab669

Comment: I solved it. I will updated the question with the changes @sab669

Comment: Then yes, you'd want to do something like this `foreach (var row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) { Process.Start(@"\\" + row[i]; }` where `i` is the index of the cell containing the IP address